# How to find a social network by BigQuery (SQL)?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

There is a fact table about shopping with below attributes.

| CustomerId | ProductId |
| --- | --- |
| C1 | P1 |
| C1 | P3 |
| C2 | P2 |
| C2 | P3 |
| C3 | P4 |
| C4 | P2 |
| C5 | P4 |
| C5 | P6 |
| C6 | P6 |

It describes which Customer purchased what product.

Now, I want to build a cluster with same interest.

```
For e.g.


C1 bought P1 & P3.
P3 bought by C2 as well, so C1 & C2 have common interest because both bought P3. 

Now C2 also bought P2 and P2 bought by C4 as well. 
So C2 and C4 also have common interest because both bought P2. 

Thus, C1 is connected to C2 and C2 connect to C4. 
hence C1, C2 & C4 all together forms a network.
```

I want an output like this, Where NetworkId should be an unique id for each network.

| NetworkId | CustomerId |
| --- | --- |
| N1 | C1 |
| N1 | C2 |
| N1 | C4 |
| N2 | C3 |
| N2 | C5 |
| N2 | C6 |

It seems like a graph problem but I am trying to solve it using BigQuery (SQL), any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yoy want to find the components of a finite graph https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory) SQL is not the best tool for the task.

Comment: I agree that SQL is not best option for solving graph problems but can we solve this with SQL?

Answer (score 1):

Consider below approach

```
with recursive init as (
  select distinct least(t1.CustomerId, t2.CustomerId) id1, greatest(t1.CustomerId, t2.CustomerId) id2
  from your_table t1
  join your_table t2
  on t1.ProductId = t2.ProductId
  and t1.CustomerId != t2.CustomerId
), iterations as (
  select id1 networkId, id1, [id1] net from init where id1 not in (select distinct id2 from init) 
  union all 
  select networkId, id2, net || [id2]
  from iterations a
  join init b
  using(id1)
)
select row_number() over() networkId, array (
  select distinct id
  from t.net id
) CustomerId
from (
  select networkId, array_concat_agg(net) net
  from iterations
  group by networkId
) t
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Mikhail, it did work on a test table but my actual table has 1 million records. On the 1M records this query keep running for more than 100 minutes and then terminated with error "Resources exceeded during query execution: Your project or organization exceeded the maximum disk and memory limit available for shuffle operations. Consider provisioning more slots, reducing query concurrency, or using more efficient logic in this job". It's 'Slot time consumed' shows more than 187 days.